# Ocultar segundo elemento de um conjunto de classes

Tags: html, css

Considere o seguinte código:

```
   <article>

      <div class="entry-meta">
       <span class="category-link"><a href="#" >Nome da Categoria</a></span>
        <a class="author vcard" href="#" rel="author">
          Por <span class="fn">Autor</span> 
      </a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="entry-meta">
      <span class="category-link"><a href="#" >Quero ocultar esse conteúdo aqui/a></span>
      <a class="author vcard" href="#" rel="author">
          Por <span class="fn">Autor</span></a>
      </div>    

   </article>
```

Estou tentando ocultar o conteúdo da segunda classe **category-link** do article:

Tentei duas formas diferentes, mas não deu certo, vejam:

```
article div:nth-of-type(2) .category-link a {
   display: none;
}

article div:nth-of-type(2) span .category-link a {
   display: none;
}
```

Onde eu estou errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nth-child(2)` direto na classe `.entry-meta` como abaixo. E tem um `</a>` no seu código que vc escreveu errado...

Mas o seu problema é que vc escreveu `span .category-link` e deveria ser `span.category-link`  com a tag.classe, sem o espaço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.entry-meta:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
.entry-meta:nth-child(2) .category-link {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<article>

  <div class="entry-meta">
    <span class="category-link"><a href="#">Nome da Categoria</a></span>
    <a class="author vcard" href="#" rel="author">
      Por <span class="fn">Autor</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="entry-meta">
    <span class="category-link"><a href="#">Quero ocultar esse conteúdo aqui</a></span>
    <a class="author vcard" href="#" rel="author">
      Por <span class="fn">Autor</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</article>
```

Comment: Show! Muito obrigado.

Comment: @Luis sem problemas meu caro, tmj!